# Format error with ESP8266 compile

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, core-libraries

I get this error when I try to compile and upload the code for the ESP826612E

```
fork/exec /home/c/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++: exec format error
```

I don't understand what the problem is, It was working fine for days until today.

Anyone has solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running a 32-bit compiler on a 64-bit operating system. You will need to install the 32-bit support libraries.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```